# Getting the base name of a file using <filesystem>

Tags: c++

In the case of a path like: "C:/Dir/foo.txt", the base name of the file would be "foo". I used to be able to do it like this:

```
#include <filesystem>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::tr2::sys;
...
path p("C:/Dir/foo.txt");
auto base = p.basename();    // base will now be "foo"
```

This worked when I used visual studio 2013. Now in the newer version (2015) it will not compile giving me the error:

*Error  C2039   'basename': is not a member of 'std::experimental::filesystem::v1::path'*

What is the equivalent function, or the way to do what I need in the new compiler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This now appears to be called [`stem()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/path/stem)

> Returns the filename identified by the path stripped of its extension.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be wanting [filename](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874769.aspx#Anchor_12)

Comment: No, that returns `foo.txt`, not `foo`.